# Java time interval percentage with greater precision

Tags: java, time, overflow, long-integer, intervals

I have the following Java code:

```
public class Time {

  private Main m;
  private long st;
  private long et;

  public Time(Main m, long g){
    this.m = m;
    st = System.currentTimeMillis();
    et = st+g;
  }

  public void update() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float per;
    if (st >= et || now >= et) {
      m.setPer(100);
      return;
    }
    if (now <= st) {
      m.setPer(000);
      return;
    }
    per = (now - st) * 100 / (et - st);
    System.out.println(per);
    m.setPer(per);  
  }

}
```

which sets the percent of time out of the interval length has passed, which is used to render the same percentage of the border of a circle as the percentage of the interval.

My problem is that I require greater precision than is lent by the long type, because it is jumpy.

When I cast the variables to float or double, it overflows.

How can I get greater precision under these circumstances?

Comment: Did you take a look at the BigInteger class ?

Comment: I think double should be able to represent it. Try using `(now - st) * 100d / (et - st)`, this will force java to evaluate your expression as double (you have to change the type of `per` to double of course).

Comment: Julien: Doesn't the BigInteger class work with integers, as the name implies? My problem is decimal precision.   

Katona: That worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arithmatic needs to be done as a double.  You may be able to modify the update function 
as follows to get the result you are after.
Notice this line in particular:

```
per = (now - st) * 100.0 / (et - st);
```

The code below changes the variables used to from longs.

```
public void update() {
  double now = (double)System.currentTimeMillis();
  double per;
  if (st >= et || now >= et) {
System.out.println ("st: " + st + ", et: " + et);
System.out.println(100);
    return;
  }
  if (now <= st) {
System.out.println(000);
    return;
  }
  per = (now - st) * 100.0 / (et - st);
  System.out.println(per);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.nanoTime() should be what you are looking for with nanotime precision.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't need more precise time; I need more precise arithmetic with the time.